# Changing value of an int, when the Button is clicked

Tags: java, swing

I made a simple program in Java and I want `numClick` variable value to be set to 0 when the "restart" `JMenuItem` is clicked. What I have now is not changing anything.

Code:

```
public class Tests {

    JButton b1 = new JButton("Click Me");
    public int numClick = 0;
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("You have clicked the button 0 times");

    public Tests() {
        frame();
    }

    public void frame() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        JMenuItem restart = new JMenuItem("Restart");
        p.add(b1);
        p.add(l1);  
        mb.add(file);
        file.add(exit);
        file.add(restart);
        f.add(p);
        f.setJMenuBar(mb);

        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        restart.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                numClick = 0;
            }
        });

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                numClick++;
                l1.setText("You have clicked the button " + numClick + " times");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tests();
    }
}
```

Comment: "not working properly" is a bad description. what's not working, what do you expect it to do and what does it actually do?

Comment: It appears that you're already almost there. Simply add the line, `l1.setText("You have clicked the button " + numClick + " times");` in the restart's ActionListener actionPerformed method after setting numClick to 0. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

Just update text in restart action listener

```
restart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        numClick = 0;
        l1.setText("You have clicked the button " + numClick + " times");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're already almost there. Simply add the line, `l1.setText("You have clicked the button " + numClick + " times");` in the restart's ActionListener actionPerformed method after setting numClick to 0. That's it.

```
restart.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        numClick = 0;

        // simply add this line, that's it.
        l1.setText("You have clicked the button " + numClick + " times");
    }
});
```